# Can anyone tell me why this would be a circular reference? Or at least point me to what a circular reference is?

Tags: javascript, json, circular-reference

I have this code snippet, which works great somewhere else, but gives me a circular reference error when I move it to a different section.  I can't even find a good reference on what a circular reference is anywhere.

```
// Create a new array to hold each of the Properties from the custom search pane
// This array will eventually be converted to JSON and become a List<Property>
propertyTables = [];

// Create new Object to hold a row - we have to construct these 
// Property objects manually for each row
propertyRow = {};

// This needs to be rewritten to include all of hidden input elements from the custom object that is clicked
// For each of the data elements the properties table, add it to the Object
$(this).parent().find('.editablePropertyList .customPropertyPrompt, .editablePropertyList .customPropertyDataType, .editablePropertyList .customPropertyInquirySearchType, .editablePropertyList .customPropertyID, .editablePropertyList .customPropertyText').each(function(index) {
    propertyValue = $(this).val();
    propertyText = $(this).text();
    switch ($(this).attr("class")) {
        case "customPropertyID":
            propertyRow.propertyID = propertyValue;
            break;
        case "customPropertyDataType":
            propertyRow.dataType = propertyValue;
            break;
        case "customPropertyPrompt":
            propertyRow.prompt = propertyText;
            break;
        case "customPropertyInquirySearchType":
            propertyRow.inquirySearchType = propertyValue;
            break;
        case "customPropertyText":
            // Whenever it reaches this data element, this means
            // that the iteration is at the end of a row.  Push the
            // newly filled propertyRow object (typeof Property) on
            // the PropertyTable array.  Then reinstance the propertyRow
            // object and it will start populating with the next row
            // as the next iteration occurs with propertyID
            propertyRow.inquirySearchText = propertyValue;
            if (propertyRow.inquirySearchText !== "") {
                propertyTables.push(propertyRow);
            }
                propertyRow = {};
                break;
            }
    });


    var statusFilter = [];
    var limitAnnotation = [];


    searchCriteria = {}; // Created the object
    searchCriteria.topFolderListBox = topFoldersWithSomeSelected; // Add the List<topLevelFolders> as the first property
    searchCriteria.docTypesListBox = docTypesWithSomeSelected; // Add the List<DocumentType> as the second property
    searchCriteria.propertyTable = propertyTables; // Add the List<Property> as the third property
    searchCriteria.statusFilter = statusFilter; // Add the List<statusFilter> as the fourth property
    searchCriteria.limitAnnotation = limitAnnotation; // Add the List<limitAnnotation> as the fifth property
    searchCriteria.fromDate = ""; // Add the string fromDate as the sixth property
    searchCriteria.toDate = ""; // Add the string toDate as the seventh property
    searchCriteria.dateRangeRelativeToday = false;
    searchCriteria.annotationText = ""; // Add the string annotationText as the eigth and final property

    // Convert to JSON String - craps out here with circular reference error
    textToSend = JSON.stringify(searchCriteria, null, "");
```

Comment: Circular reference: if the JSON serializer (`stringify`) finds itself somewhere it's already been as it's recursing through the object's properties, it will throw the error you're seeing to prevent an infinite loop. So somehow, somewhere, some field of the `searchCriteria` object is pointing back to either `searchCritera` itself or one of its subfields.

Comment: You use `topFoldersWithSomeSelected` and `docTypesWithSomeSelected` in the object, but you haven't shown how you create them. As you don't create circular reference in the code that you have shown, that's where the circular reference is.

Comment: Guffa - you were right - the circular reference was actually in topFoldersWithSomeSelect - which I generated with:  topFoldersWithSomeSelected = $(this).parent().find('.companyList .folderID').map(function () { return $(this).val(); });  Using the jQuery map function returns an object with the reference to the original - I used $.makeArray to convert to array and it serialized fine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Circular Reference**

In short: It is when `objA` contains a reference to `objB` which in turn contains a reference to `objA`.. and so on. You will have an infinite series like that.

A simplest example:

```
var a = {}
var b = {}
a['x'] = b;
b['y'] = a;
```

In the above case, `a` object contains a key `x` which refers to `b`. And in the similar fashion, `b` object contains a key `y` which refers to `a`  back again.

This is a classic problem while serialising (like JSON in this case):

```
serialise a ->
    serialise value of key x in a ->  # == b
        serialise b ->
            serialise value of key y in b -> # ==a
                serialise a ->
                    ... and so on..
```

The error that I get (in Chrome) when trying the above code:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

---

About your problem, it is really difficult to tell where exactly is the circular reference without looking at the entire code. I would suggest one thing. Do a `console.log(searchCriteria)`. If your browser shows a tree like structure go on expanding the nodes until you hit a node which you have seen before (at lesser depth).

And when you see something like the below, you know what is the culprit. :)
[image: Circular reference problem]