# Uncaught TypeError in javascript function

Tags: javascript, json, html, session-storage

```
Storage.prototype.setObj = function(key, obj) {
    return this.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(obj))
    ^-----Error in this line: Uncaught TypeError: Accessing selectionDirection on an input element that cannot have a selection
}
var selected = jQuery('input:checkbox.mychkbox:checked').each(function() {
        return this.id;
});
sessionStorage.setObj("savedCollSearch",selected);
```

I am using jQuery 1.7.2 and Chrome 22.
This error shows up as Uncaught Exception in Firefox 16. Search in SO and Google does not help and I have no clue how to resolve this.

I am 100% sure jQuery is loaded properly.

Comment: Selected is string not json object

Comment: @Amareswar: selected is a json object.

Comment: @raina77ow: you should read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage

Comment: @Amareswar: There is no such thing as a "json object".

Comment: @RocketHazmat: javascript object? here.

Comment: @RocketHazmat What about `JSON` itself? )

Comment: @raina77ow: Well, you got me there :-P  It just bugs me a little when people say "json object", it's a "JavaScript object".  JSON is a string representation of data that happens to resemble JavaScript object syntax.

Comment: @exception, I mean javascript object. As JSON.parse is being used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This expression...

```
var selected = jQuery('input:checkbox.mychkbox:checked').each(function() {
  return this.id;
});
```

... seems to be misused here: it'll return you a jQuery-wrapped collection of checked checkbox elements, which is probably not quite easy to stringify (because of circular references).

*(as a sidenote, `.each` will stop the iteration at the first element which doesn't have an `id`, or have it set to an empty string, but that doesn't matter much here)*

You probably wanted to use this instead:

```
var selected = jQuery('input:checkbox.mychkbox:checked').map(function() {
  return this.id;
}).get();
```

Comment: I had it as map instead of each, until I read here:http://stackoverflow.com/a/749119/1446848 that map is more memory intensive than each. Can you point me to some documentation on "circular references". Never heard of that before in javascript.

Comment: @exception: `map` and `each` are different functions used for different purposes.  Use the correct one for what you are doing, stop the micro-optimizations!  One may be more "memory intensive", but unless you have like 1,000,000 elements, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @exception Why, there's [a](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816099/chrome-sendrequest-error-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json) [whole](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11298018/can-anyone-tell-me-why-this-would-be-a-circular-reference-or-at-least-point-me) [lot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410162/javascript-circumvent-error-converting-circular-structure-to-json-when-doing-js) of such questions here at SO. Even a special tag for that. )

Comment: @exception Of course, it's memory intensive - `map` is used to _return_ a collection, so it has to store the result somewhere. ) `each`, on the other side, usually just _does_ something for each element of collection.